# extends a class with default mapping

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I search a way to have the same base point for different controller

I know i could do

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/extranet")
public class BillingController {

    @GetMapping("/billing")
    public String getBilling() {
        return "Hi From billing!!";
    }
}



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/extranet")
public class PublicationController {

    @GetMapping("/publication")
    public String getPublication() {
        return "Hi From publication!!";
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The First Way - makes the `annotation`

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/extranet")
public @interface ExtranetRestController {

}
```

and Add `annotation` on controller

```
@ExtranetRestController
public class BillingController {

  @GetMapping("/billing")
  public String getBilling() {
    return "Hi From billing!!";
  }
}

@ExtranetRestController
public class PublicationController {

  @GetMapping("/publication")
  public String getPublication() {
    return "Hi From publication!!";
  }
}
```

### The Second Way - makes the `context-path`

Add under line in `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-path=/extranet
```

and Modify controllers

```
@RestController
public class BillingController {

  @GetMapping("/billing")
  public String getBilling() {
    return "Hi From billing!!";
  }
}

@RestController
public class PublicationController {

  @GetMapping("/publication")
  public String getPublication() {
    return "Hi From publication!!";
  }
}
```

Comment: You really only save a few keystrokes. You still need `ExtranetRestController` on every controller, may as well use `@RequestMapping("/extranet")`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Thank for your advice. I added the Second Way.